# How to connect to PostgreSQL without VPN?

Tags: postgresql

***Background***: My company has a PostgreSQL DB which allows access only through corporate VPN. I'm in the phase of developing a simple chatbot which fetches information (Shipment Status) from the Postgres DB. The chatbot will be used by Client's team who do not have access to our corporate VPN.

***Question:*** Is there a way to avoid the VPN dependency? So that Client can use the Chatbot application to get information without actually having to log into VPN.

I have few basic thoughts about this (I might be very wrong, but giving it a shot):

1. Maybe having a different Port number which will bypass the VPN?
2. Migrating the DB to a Cloud instance such as AWS RDS and then querying info from there?
3. Connecting to PostgreSQL API to get the information (Assuming it only requires API Key to access information and not a VPN connection)

As I mentioned, my idea of above points can be completely wrong but would love to hear your thoughts and ideas to overcome this.

***P.S:*** The Chatbot is designed in such a way that only the Shipment Status information can be obtained from it, which cannot be classified as confidential information. So ideally anyone with a valid Shipment ID should be able to use the Chatbot application.

Comment: Your bot shouldn't connect directly to the databases but to a service running in your company's network that talks to the database

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, thanks for your response. Could you please elaborate on what could be the service you're referring to?

Comment: This is a conversation you should have with your boss, not with strangers on the internet.  If your boss doesn't know what a VPN is, then you need to discuss it with both your boss and whoever is charge of the VPN.

Answer (score 1):

- Create a firewall  DMZ
- Create an API server in the DMZ which has has access to the VPN and queries the dB and returns the result to the chatbot
- Make the chatbot to use the API server to query shipment information.

Migrating to AWS could be also a viable option and this kind of behavior can be configured by using VPC and other AWS services.

Comment: Thanks for your response. This is all very new to me, I will take some time to research about your points. This process that you mentioned, does it have a specific name to it? Something that people in the industry have been using? I'm asking this only for the ease of my research.

Comment: Also, I was wondering if I happen to migrate AWS RDS, would my clients be able to access the information (through chatbot) just by signing in with their Google accounts (or) without the need of login/sign in?

Comment: DMZ stands for Demilitarized Zone so you can use it with other network related terms.

Comment: If you migrate to AWS you could allow users to make queries unauthenticated (using AWS API Gateway to create an open API or just use a Lambda function to retrieve information). It is also possible to use AWS Cognito to allow users to authenticate themselves by using social logins like Google and Facebook.